# Problems with Windows boot loader and Grub. How to make one primary and the other secondary?

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, grub, multi-boot

I had a working Windows 7 + Ubuntu 10.10 setup where my primary boot loader was that of Windows 7 and from there when I went on Ubuntu, it took me to Grub.

When I updated to Ubuntu 11.04 it made Grub the primary loader - when I went to Windows 7 from Grub it took me to the Windows loader to start the system. I've tried to repair the Windows boot loader with the hope of making it primary again, but when I go to the repair and it scans for the system, it actually finds the Windows partition but then tells me it is an older system and can't be repaired.

I didn't tell where the new Grub must install, it was installed as an update with the update of the ubuntu. On disk C:/ is the windows, after it is a second partition D:/Storage, where I keep all my programs and stuff, after them is are the linux partions that are hidden (Partion 1 is the installation partion where I installed the Ubuntu and it's grub and partion 2 for my linux things) . There was another partion with a letter H:/ created by windows 7 for its boot loader files. But when I installed the ubuntu it showed up.In order to hide it again, I've changed the label from H:/ to A:/ so I could make it hidden again. And there was no problem 'till I've updated ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04. I forgot to tell you that I'm knew at ubuntu, and I don't know how exactly to point to it where GRUB is.

Is there a way to make the Windows boot loader primary again without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Take a look at this... http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, exactly what you do depends from exactly how you've messed things up.  You haven't provided anywhere near enough information for other people to determine that.  (The output of the `list partition` command from `diskpart` is required, at minimum.)  In general, therefore:

You must …

- … ensure that you restore the correct bootstrap program in your Master Boot Record, using [`bootsect /mbr /nt60 ALL`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744577%28WS.10%29.aspx) or some such.
- … ensure that your [system partition](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/boot-and-system-volumes.html), where Microsoft's Boot Manager lives, is the "startable"/"active" partition, using your choice of disc partitioning tool.
- … bring up to date the *old* instance of GRUB2 that is no doubt installed in your Ubuntu boot partition, which wasn't updated when you installed a *second* copy of GRUB2 elsewhere (which is quite probably what you've done), and make sure that Ubuntu knows that that's where GRUB2 lives.